# No Message Notification From Android Phone

Tags: iphone, ios, notifications, sms, android

I have an iPhone 8 running iOS 11.4.1 and I have run into a rather annoying problem with the Messages app that I can't seem to remedy. My wife has an Android phone and I'm finding I am no longer receiving SMS notifications sounds when I receive a message from her. I have checked to see if her contact or the phone has been set to "Do Not Disturb", but it has not. Sometimes I get the notification sound and the screen lights up as expected but it seems to happen only when I receive an SMS from an Android device. Whenever I receive a message from a iPhone it works everytime.

Anyone else run into this problem?

Comment: Extremely annoying. I was just going to post this same problem.

Comment: I actually found that if you go Settings > Notifications > Settings and enable notifications on Lock Screen, Notification Centre and Banner seems to fix the problem

Comment: I have that set already. :(